# DateTimeOffset TotalHours returns different values

Tags: c#, .net, datetimeoffset

The following code returns 9.25 when I feel it should return 8.25, what have I misunderstood?

```
(new DateTimeOffset(2014,09,04,08,15,00,new TimeSpan(0,0,0))).Subtract(new DateTimeOffset(2014,09,04,08,15,00,new TimeSpan(0,0,0)).Date).TotalHours
```

more simply shown as:-

```
DateTimeOffset start = new DateTimeOffset(2014,09,04,08,15,00,new TimeSpan(0,0,0));
double result = start.Subtract(start.Date).TotalHours
```

When run on a Windows 7 PC in Time Zone GMT (adjust for Daylight Saving time) on:-

12th September result = 9.25

12th December result = 8.25

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the [`DateTimeOffset.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.date(v=vs.110).aspx) property returns a `DateTime` with a `Kind` of unspecified. That's then assumed to be system-local when you subtract it from the `DateTimeOffset`.

You can fix this by asking for the `UtcDateTime` and get the `Date` from that:

```
double result = start.Subtract(start.UtcDateTime.Date).TotalHours
```

Of course, that's assuming that the `Date` that you want is the date on which the *UTC* date/time falls. We don't know much about your actual requirements. You might want to consider using my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library to avoid this sort of ambiguity though - with more types to choose from, it allows you to specify your intentions more clearly.

Comment: Thank you, driving me crazy for some time, as Development and production are in different time zones.

Comment: I have read up on Noda Time several times in the last year - this is possibly the right time to ask about compatibility to SQL server DateTimeOffset(7) via Entity Framework 5 DateTimeOffset types. Will I be converting to / from DateTimeOffsets all the time, thus relying on creating a pattern for evolution of the C# code rather than being able to embed the intentions of my design into the POCO objects?

Comment: @Oldfart: I'm afraid EF doesn't support the use of custom types directly. But you shouldn't need to do it "all the time" - typically you just create a "buddy property" I believe (I'm not an EF person myself). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143549 - then most of your code can just use Noda Time, and it'll convert from `OffsetDateTime` to `DateTimeOffset` for persistence.