# Date Time Struct to deal with different time zones

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, struct, timezone

I  make struct name DateTimeZone , I set it to take the UTC time and I get it to take local time.

```
    DateTimeZone time = DateTime.Now;//time will equal the UTC time
    DateTime localTime= time; // local time will equal the Local time
```

the struct

```
  public struct DateTimeZone
{
    private DateTime dateTime;

 //   public  DateTimeZone Value { get; }

    public static implicit operator DateTimeZone(DateTime value)
    {
        return new DateTimeZone() { dateTime = value.ToUniversalTime() };
    }

    public static implicit operator DateTime(DateTimeZone value)
    {
        return value.dateTime.ToLocalTime();
    }
}
```

My question : is there easiest way to implement this than struct?
and this struct have exception when i save in DB cause entity frame work,
so I need to make mapping every time I use struct , How I can make mapping in concise manner?

Comment: `DateTime` is timezone _awareness_. It is _not_ clear what you try to do, honestly, but it would be better to use [Nodatime](http://nodatime.org/) which is a better API for DateTime.

Comment: thank you, I have problem with time zone , so i need datetime to save utc time in db always & to get local time when show it UI, I modify the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- Be careful with your naming.  An object with a name like `DateTimeZone` would be expected to contain either 1) time zone information only, or 2) a date and time and time zone.  Your object is only an encapsulation wrapper around `DateTime`, so it is neither of these things.
- Implicit operations can be evil - especially if they change the meaning of the value you're working with.  I don't recommend using them with date/time, unless you *really* know what you're doing.  It will quickly become confusing to any user of this object as to what value you were actually working with.
- The `ToUniversalTime` and `ToLocalTime` functions change their behavior based on the `DateTimeKind` assigned to the `.Kind` property of the `DateTime` objects you're working with.  You seem to be creating an API in which `DateTime` is always local and `DateTimeZone` is always UTC, but `DateTimeKind` will get in the way of this idea.
- As mentioned in comments, you might look into using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), which is a very solid and well-thought-out API.  In Noda Time, the `Instant` type always represents UTC, and the `LocalDateTime` type always represents a timezoneless date and time.  Time zones are represented by `DateTimeZone` (see the conflict with your name), and the `ZonedDateTime` type combines these, such that you have both instant-in-time information, local-time information, and the associated time zone.
- You mentioned Entity Framework.  Unfortunately, EF will not work directly with either your custom object, or with Noda Time.  It does not have the ability to do simple type conversions.  This has been requested, but not yet implemented.  [You can follow the work item for it here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/242).  A workaround you can use is "buddy properties", [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25155924/634824).  They're not fun, but they work. Mostly.
- You may find it reasonable to just use `DateTime`, and call methods like `ToUniversalTime` or `ToLocalTime` manually, when needed.  If you want EF to properly set `DateTimeKind` when loading from the database, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19301623/634824).
- Keep in mind that both `ToUniversalTime` and `ToLocalTime` work with the computer's local time zone where the code happens to be running.  This works fine for desktop and mobile applications, but is rarely desired for web applications, because changing the time zone of the server could drastically affect the data.  Consider instead working with a named time zone via the built-in `TimeZoneInfo` class, or with the `DateTimeZone` class in Noda Time.

Additional reading for you:

- [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices)
- [The timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try this one:

```
public struct DateTimeZone
{
    public DateTime DateTime;

    public static explicit operator DateTimeZone(DateTime dt)
    {
        return new DateTimeZone { DateTime = dt.ToUniversalTime() };
    }
}

var time = (DateTimeZone)DateTime.Now;
var localTime = time.DateTime;
```